# Add facets to the Content Editor search page

Tags: content-editor, content-search

I have a folder which is a bucket and I'm using the search functionality to get the results. 
By default I have 4 facets on the right column: Template, Language, Author and Date Range.

[image]
I see on the path: /sitecore/system/Settings/Buckets/Facets
that there are a few out of the box facets there. I have tried to create a new facet but it's not showing on the facets column.

[image]

Anyone know what I'm missing? I will need to add 3 other facets so looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Can you make sure that field exists in the index (probably sitecore_master_index)? You can use luke (https://github.com/DmitryKey/luke) to see the contents of the index.

Comment: did you reindex sitecore_master_index before you search ?

Comment: yes I reindexed it

Comment: what is contenttype? is it a custom index field?

Comment: Also [here](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/search_and_item_buckets/facets) is the official facet creation document on this topic.

Comment: The problem is that the field is not being indexed. 
 I have followed the guideline on how to setup but as I said that contenttype field was not getting indexed being why the facets were not showing up

Comment: This 'Content Type' field is Sitecore's OOTB field or custom? Because from your screenshots I think you should be meaning to say 'Mime Type' which has the file extensions stored.

Comment: it's a custom field

Comment: can you add code for computed index field and configuration files. did you try to debug the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being that the contenttype field was not getting indexed properly and the facets didn't work because of that.
Also the facets will only show on the Search page facets if the facet does exist on the results